# How to make angularJS $watch to detect changes in style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scope, watch

I am having a rich text box with all the style controls.

When I enter a new text in it - it saves.

When I make any changes in the content (text) along with some styles like color highlighting and bold text - it saves the changed text and styles.

But, when I just make style changes without any content change - it won't save those style changes.

I am using $watch to compare new value and old value.

How to make it work even for style changes?

Comment: Can you attach your code please?

Answer (score 10):

```
angular.module("app",[]).directive('spyStyle', [function () {

    return {

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return element.css(attrs['spyAttribute']);
            },  styleChangedCallBack,
            true);

            function styleChangedCallBack(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    // do something interesting here
                }
            }

        }
    };

}]);
```

In your HTML:

```
<div spy-style spy-attribute="height" >
```

In case you want to execute custom functions outside the directive:

```
<div spy-style="functionNameToExecute" spy-attribute="height" >
```

In your Directive code make this change:

```
angular.module("app",[]).directive('spyStyle', [function () {

    return {

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return element.css(attrs['spyAttribute']);
            },  styleChangedCallBack,
            true);

            function styleChangedCallBack(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    // do something interesting here
                    // invoking callback function:
                    scope[attrs['spyStyle']](newValue);
                }
            }

        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: This approach is not working for my case. I have Bootstrap tabbed form, and I am watching the style attribute 'display' of the last tab which has a canvas. If the value of 'display' changes from 'none' to 'block' then I want to trigger resize event to redraw the canvas living inside this tab. I think I need to call $scope.$digest() to make it work, but I don't know how. I am using custom directive for to control the last tab and watch the display css attribute. During debug I can see that watch but it seems it's running too early and not function all the times.